# Hexagon Atom circle wire frame

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to achieve a hexagon alike shape Image 1, But I cannot figure out how to make the projecting vertices looking like image 1, ellipse/circular, Mine are hollow and hexagonal like the mesh sphere, I understand this result because I'm using the wireframe modifier, ( if its the correct approach towards the result..). How can I achieve a similar result like image 1?

[image]

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/is-it-possible-to-render-vertices-in-blender

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dupliverts.

Add a big icosphere and at its center, a small one.

Parent the small one to the big one. (select small, then big, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, Object)

Select the big sphere,go to Object panel, in Duplication, click Verts.

The little sphere is now replicated on every vertex of the big one. Notice that the faces of the big sphere won't be rendered, despite they appear in the 3D view.

Now you can duplicate the big sphere (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), disable duplications on it, and add a Wireframe modifier.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying. All seems to be turning out well, until I get to the last step. I duplicate the large sphere, and add the wireframe  modifier. But the parenting small sphere with the duplicated vertices are large, and I cannot figure out how to scale them down, simultaneously. Please have a look at the image I have uploaded. I can also do a quick recording of the steps you have provided me if my image doesnt make sense, so you can possibly locate what I am doing wrong.

Comment: All good, I figured it out!

Kind regards.