# Geometry Nodes - Point Cloud from custom XYZ coordinates?

Tags: python, vertices, geometry, point-clouds, geometry-nodes

I'd like to create a *point cloud* using the *Geometry Node Editor* based on my own custom data.

[image]

The data is stored in a .txt file, plain [x,y,z] coordinates and looks like this:

```
v1 : 1, 2, 1; 
v2: 1.5, 2, 0; 
v3: 0, 2.5, 2; 
v4: 1.2, 2, 0; 
etc.
```

I also tried a python script to import the vertices, which is working fine but I don't find a way to use it for *Geometry Nodes*.

**Q:** Is there any way to create a point cloud based on the given data to make use of *Geometry Nodes* features in order to further manipulate the point cloud?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points

Comment: If the data has been imported as vertex per coordinate, it's technically a *point cloud* already. Just wondering what's your question...? Do you'd like to visualize the point cloud?

Comment: Yes, I want to visualize point cloud. I have few coordinates [x, y, z]. My expectation is that I will create Point Cloud like it is in Blender 2.93 (Cube with random points) and every point will belong to my coordinates [x, y, z].

Then I will continue in Geometry Node Editor where I want to set to every point in cloud different object.

The problem is that I dont know how to create Point Cloud from my vertices instead of random points.

Comment: See: [Is it possible to render vertices in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/is-it-possible-to-render-vertices-in-blender). Again, a set of vertices is a point cloud, goal achieved. Suggest add your comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have problem when I create Point Cloud (Experimental in Blender >2.92) that  the points in cloud are distributed randomly. I want to have them in positions which I set)

Comment: Don't know this feature but if they are distributed randomly, it's obviously not the right feature to use. I'd suggest import them using python, see my first comment. Otherwise please edit your question, share your data and explain in detail what your goal is, thanks.

Comment: oki, I will describe it better with my data

Comment: I want to create **Point Cloud** like this:

https://imgur.com/a/OMGf1bb.jpg

The points inside have some **coordinates [x, y ,z]**.

I have my own coordinates: 
v1 : 1, 2, 1;
v2: 1.5, 2, 0;
v3: 0, 2.5, 2;
v4: 1.2, 2, 0;
etc.

I want to set points in cloud to my coordinates via Python script.

I need it like this, because then I am using Geometry Editor.

Comment: Ok, I think I am finally getting close:
bpy.ops.object.pointcloud_add(align='WORLD', location=(0,0,0), scale=(1,1,1))
obj = context.active_object
for i in range (0, 35):
    obj.data.points[i].co = (0,0,0)
v = obj.data.points[30].co 
print(v)

Comment: I have edited the question for you. If something is wrong, please correct it. Also please  add what you call the "Geometry Editor". Do you mean geometry nodes by that?

Comment: Thanks. I mean Geometry Node Editor

Comment: I have edited the question for you again. Instead of comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your
question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add information to 
your post.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem lately as well, If you have the points as vertices you can use something like this node setup to get a renderable point cloud [image: pointcloud]

In case you find it useful I've put together an addon [blender_plots](https://github.com/Linusnie/blender_plots) which automatically generates such node trees from numpy arrays and also supports adding a different color to each point